# PHP move_uploaded_file dynamic file name - files have no extension

Tags: php, file, upload

I want to upload some GPX (XML technically) files to the server and rename them with dynamic file names (such as 0.gpx, 1.gpx ... ). I can not figure out how to do this with the move_uploaded_file function as it only creates the files extensionless. I get a 'name' file instead of a 'name.gpx' file.

Shouldn't it use the PATHINFO_EXTENSION of the uploadef file automatically to create the file with the right extension?

I have tried to call the function like this:

```
$filename = 0;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfiles']['tmp_name'][$f], $filename);
$filename++;
```

Even if I try to create a string with the extension it does not work:

```
$tmp = 0;
$ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filename = $tmp + "." + $ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfiles']['tmp_name'][$f], $filename);
$tmp++;
```

Help please?

Comment: If you're wondering/asking whether it will create the extension for you, the answer is no. Read the manual http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File name should have the extension. This works fine for me to find the extension:

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["uploadfiles"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

echo $extension; // Display the extension

$tmp = 0;
$filename = $tmp.".".$extension;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfiles']['tmp_name'][$f], $filename);
$tmp++;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I thought I had to craft a string by using '+', but you got it right.

Comment: Please match the extension in a whitelist because anyone could upload php script, or other nasty things otherwise.

Comment: This web application is just an exercise for university, so I just need it on localhost. I matched it already in a whitelist, though, just wasn't necessary to add here for my question. Thank you anyway.

Comment: glad to help you, concatenating in PHP uses dot `.` .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think temporary files have an extension.

You could manually add "gpx" to the name :

```
$tmp = 0;
$filename = $tmp . ".gpx";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfiles']['tmp_name'][$f], $filename);
$tmp++;
```

Or maybe check the mimetype and craft the appropriate extension out of it.

Or take the extension in `$_FILES['uploadfiled']['name']`, match it in a whitelist, and append it to your final filename.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with the '+', I tried that myself too. When I do it like UserProg suggested above, it works. Thanks anyway.